# when using python open() on mac, getting "[Errno 2] no such file or directory: 'file:///absolute/path/' ", path generated from MLflow

Tags: python-3.x, macos, mlflow, nosuchfileexception

I imagine this has been answered, but I could not find.

I am attempting to use:

```
with open('file:///absolute/path/to/file') as fn:
     csv-stuff
```

however, I am getting Error :

> "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file:///absolute/path/to/file'"

The absolute file path is being generated within the following commands from os and mlflow:

```
data_uri = os.path.join(run.info.artifact_uri, "data")
```

where "data" was logged without a artifact_path specified with:

```
mlflow.log_artifact(tempfile_path,"data")
```

I have been stuck on this for a few days and have not figured out the issue yet. Thanks for the help!

P.S. This is my first post, feel free to tell me if I am doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I did not understand the nuances between system path and uri's. I used the second answer submitted in the link from @MihaiChelaru's comment and it worked out. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I believe you can accept the duplicate target, which will show others that it solved your problem and turn this question into a signpost for the other question. I thought about writing up a solution in this case, but I realized there are other nuances in these URIs such as URI-escaped characters that need to be handled. Glad you were able to make it work with their solution!